# If an image can be recreated using strictly CSS, is there still a purpose for that image?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, coding-style

I previously had some images on my site in the form of simple pills with border and a background color. They act as login/register, add to cart, etc "buttons" that when clicked give an action.

Considering the simplicity of these images, they can be remade 1:1 in CSS quite easily. While the below snippet isn't quite 1:1, it's close enough to visualize how similar a purely CSS option can be. The second pill is the image the CSS is recreating.

```css
.butt {
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #cc5a5a;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="butt">No Stock</div> <br/> <br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhjht.png" alt=""/>
```

A lot of sites I see still use sprites for rudimentary navigation, like chevrons or arrows for left/right, simple text as linked images to pages and more. I have to wonder why these are not done in CSS?

The way I see it, using CSS means it loads faster and is scalable. What benefit do sites gain from instead using images in place of things that could be done with CSS?

Comment: Sprites are used for lightweight scalable images that need to look good at many resolutions, but it's a personal preference.

Comment: sprites aren't scalable unless they use SVGs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A benefit would be support for older versions of browsers. Most sites still want to support as many browsers and versions as possible. And not all browser versions support every CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

**Compatibility**, not all browsers support all kinds of css.

But other than that I think you've nailed it, CSS really is the way to go.

EDIT:
It's fair to note some choose to use *sprite sheets* essentially loading one big picture and then *cutting* different images out of that sheet to gain a desired look.

Another benefit could have to do with breaking down jobs.
For example an **artist** might be in charge of designing how images (or buttons or whatever) look and can easily upload and replace images where-as the **programmer** can place them where to go.

There are benefits to both but ultimately it's up to preference and circumstance.

Comment: Say you have a bunch of "buttons" like the one I posted which share a class describing the border properties. If a website owner wanted to change how the borders look on all images, they could either go to their graphic designer and have a dozen or more images remade with the desired changes, or changing a couple lines of CSS.

Comment: That would be the "circumstance" part of my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case css is the way to go, period.

I say this because even in old browsers all you'll lose is the rounded corners on the borders and even then (with prefixes) this will only affect [less than 10% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius). and that figure will only go down over time.

It's best to support tomorrow's browser over yesterday's, unless you have a user base which you must serve who are on old browsers (maybe on a large company's intranet, or in a country where the technology is often recycled and donated) in which think of making things functional and usable first rather than looking identical to the latest browser. This is called [graceful degradation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement), the cousin of progressive enhancement (find out about both from the W3C on the link).

This [article is also useful](https://boagworld.com/design/where-are-my-rounded-corners/), particularly where clients who might be expecting those rounded corners in IE6 are concerned.

Oh, and there's also still a purpose for the image in your graphics of course :-)